# Скроллинг по якорям JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть блоки высотой в `100vh`

```
<div class="block" id="block1">
<div class="block" id="block2">
<div class="block" id="block3">
```

И нужно чтобы при скроллинге, страница перемещалась ровно к ним, вне зависимости от того, каким способом проиходит скролл (Колесо, пробел, стрелки, скроллбар). А когда пользователь находится на последнем, и скроллит дальше, его перемещало на самое начало

Upd. Попрошу вариант, без jQuery

Comment: Вам, скорее всего, проще использовать скролл слайдеры, чем городить велосипеды... Вот, например, такой: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js

Comment: Вот, бери и допиливай: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1113762/178988. При том, что тебе зацикливать не надо, там даже гораздо проще можно сделать.